# Subir varios archivos desde una api con Http Client -> A 'contents' key is required

Tags: html, laravel, api

Estoy intentando validar dos archivos y subirlos, lo hago mediante una api con **Http Client** de laravel, este es mi codigo:

```
$files = $request->file('files');
    
    $names = [];
    foreach ($files as  $file)
    {
        if(file_exists($file)){
            $name= $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $names[] = $name;
        }
    }

$response = Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data' ,'accept' => 'application/json'])
    ->attach($names, $files[0])
    ->post(env('API_URL').'user/register', $request->all());
    return $response;
```

Aparece el error **"A 'contents' key is required"**
Ya lei la documentacion, probé todo lo que había por ahí y nada.

Comment: Como no sabemos que espera esa API, difícilmente podamos ayudarte. Al parecer tienes que enviar una key  'contents'...

Comment: Eso es obvio, lo dice el mensaje de error, pero yo todo lo estoy enviando bien, los headers, y el attach, tal como esta todo en la documentación.

Comment: Y para colocarlos en contexto, la api espera varios campos, nombres apellidos, direcciones y toda eso, es un formulario, pero la api a su vez los valida con la clase Validator de laravel, y al principio cuando intentaba subir los archivos sin "attach" decía que "The :field must be a file", dado que el archivo no se enviaba como debe ser, ahora que si lo hace me aparece este nuevo error... :/

Comment: ¿Entonces, es el attach es el que te marca ese error `"A 'contents' key is required"`, no la validación de la api?

Comment: Si amigo es el Attach

Comment: Fijate que en el primer argumento le estás pasando un array, y [`attach(string|array $name, string $contents = '', string|null $filename = null, array $headers = [])`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Http.html#method_attach) espera un string con el nombre del campo que espera la api, y como segundo argumento está `contents` donde va el archivo.

Comment: Si le pasas un array en el primer argumento, attach lo va a [interpretar](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e9cd94c89f59c833c13d04f32f1e31db419a4c0c/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L235) como un array de archivos, cada uno con su name y content (y opcionalmente nombre del archivo).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129134/discussion-between-abdiel-and-porloscerros-).